# How set the bounding box for \middle

Tags: equations

Why does the bounding box of `\left` and `\right` differ from `\middle` in the third term of the following equation?  And can I make them all the same, preferably with the middle becoming short like the others.

```latex
\begin{equation}
    n\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\,\middle|\,v\right\rangle
     =\overbrace{\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\,\middle|\,v\right\rangle
    +\cdots+\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\,\middle|\,v\right\rangle}^n
    = \left\langle \overbrace{\frac{1}{n}t+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}t}^n\,\middle|\, v\right\rangle
    =\langle t\mid v\rangle
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\middle` delimiter wants to also cover the `\overbrace` items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a prime illustration of why relying uncritically on `\left`, `\middle`, and `\right` can be a poor idea. Just employ 4 instances each of `\biggl\langle`, `\biggm\vert` (and lose the `\,` spacers!), and `\biggr\rangle`, i.e., use fixed sizes.

[image]

Do note the use of a typographic strut in the following code -- `\vphantom{\bigg\vert}` -- to assure that that two overbraces are placed at the same height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    n\biggl\langle\frac{1}{n}t \biggm\vert v\biggr\rangle
    =\overbrace{%
       \biggl\langle\frac{1}{n}t \biggm\vert v\biggr\rangle
       +\dots+
       \biggl\langle\frac{1}{n}t \biggm\vert v\biggr\rangle%
       }^n
    =\biggl\langle \, 
     \overbrace{%
       \frac{1}{n}t +\dots+ \frac{1}{n}t%
       \vphantom{\bigg\vert}%  <-- insert a typographic strut
       }^n
       \biggm\vert v\biggr\rangle
    =\langle t\mid v\rangle
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Judging by the screenshot you posted, you may be be employing Palatino text and math fonts rather than the "basic" or default Computer Modern text and math fonts. If this is the case, then the use of `\bigg[lmr]` creates needlessly large delimiters. I suggest you use either `\Big[lmr]` or, if you're willing to use `\tfrac{1}{n}` instead of `\frac{1}{n}`, `\big[lmr]` to size `\langle`, `\vert`, and `\rangle`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % optional: Palatino text and math fonts
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
%% Case (a): \frac along with \Bigl, \Bigm, \Bigr
      n\Bigl\langle\frac{1}{n}t \Bigm\vert v \Bigr\rangle
    &={\overbrace{%
       \Bigl\langle\frac{1}{n}t \Bigm\vert v \Bigr\rangle
       +\dots+
       \Bigl\langle\frac{1}{n}t \Bigm\vert v \Bigr\rangle%
       }^n}
    =\Bigl\langle \, 
     \overbrace{%
       \frac{1}{n}t +\dots+ \frac{1}{n}t%
       }^n
       \Bigm\vert v \Bigr\rangle
    =\langle t\mid v \rangle \\
%% Case (b): \tfrac along with \bigl, \bigm, \bigr
      n\bigl\langle\tfrac{1}{n}t \bigm\vert v \bigr\rangle
    &={\overbrace{%
       \bigl\langle\tfrac{1}{n}t \bigm\vert v \bigr\rangle
       +\dots+
       \bigl\langle\tfrac{1}{n}t \bigm\vert v \bigr\rangle%
       }^n}
    =\bigl\langle
     \overbrace{%
       \tfrac{1}{n}t +\dots+ \tfrac{1}{n}t%
       }^n
       \bigm\vert v \bigr\rangle
    =\langle t\mid v \rangle
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Its in a publisher's format so I couldn't figure out the font, but both options worked to my liking, I suspect at least one will work for others.

Answer (score 5):

There are two independent aspects in your problem:

1. in the standard Computer Modern math fonts, the largest size of `\langle` and `\rangle` covers a display style fraction;
2. the delimiters' size is anyway chosen as to cover the whole formula, which is very high due to `\overbrace`.

For instance, if you load `yhmath` that provides for more sizes of `\langle` and `\rangle` you get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    n\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\,\middle|\,v\right\rangle
     =\overbrace{\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\,\middle|\,v\right\rangle
    +\cdots+\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\,\middle|\,v\right\rangle}^n
    = \left\langle \overbrace{\frac{1}{n}t+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}t}^n\,\middle|\, v\right\rangle
    =\langle t\mid v\rangle
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you see now that the angle brackets being like in the first part of the expression is due to a maximum size?

I wouldn't use `\left`, `\middle` and `\right` in this case. However, if you really need it, you can hide the overbrace from the size computation, provided you take it into account for the whole equation.

It's a bit of a hack, but for a couple of cases it would be not so heavy.

I left `yhmath` to show that the chosen delimiters don't grow too big. The trick is to use phantoms and smash, in one case with `\obrace` turned into a command that just typesets the material and no overbrace.

Some care is needed to get the braces and superscripts at the same height.

All in all, it's much better to use manually sized delimiters as suggested by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648267/4427).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\newcommand{\obrace}[2]{{\overbrace{#1}^{#2}}}
\newcommand{\noobrace}[2]{#1}

\begin{document}

Some text above some text above some text above some text above
some text above some text above some text above some text above
\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\myexpra}{%
  \left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\,\middle|\,v\right\rangle
  +\cdots+\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\;\middle|\;v\right\rangle
}
\newcommand{\myexprb}{\obrace{\vphantom{\myexpra}\frac{1}{n}t+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}t}{n}}
  n\left\langle\frac{1}{n}t\;\middle|\;v\right\rangle
  =
  \obrace{\myexpra}{n}
  =
  \left\langle\,
    \smash{\myexprb}\vphantom{\let\obrace\noobrace\myexprb}
  \;\middle|\;v
  \right\rangle
  =\langle t\mid v\rangle
\end{equation}
Some text below some text below some text below some text below
some text below some text below some text below some text below

\end{document}
```

By the way, `\,` is too small, use `\;`.

[image]

Or avoid fractions until the last moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\newcommand{\obrace}[2]{{\overbrace{#1}^{#2}}}

\begin{document}

If $q$ is any rational number, we have
\begin{equation*}
n\langle qt\mid v\rangle =
\obrace{\langle qt\mid v\rangle}{n} =
\langle\,\obrace{qt+\dots+qt\vphantom{\langle}}{n}\mid v\rangle =
\langle nqt\mid v\rangle
\end{equation*}
and, with $q=1/n$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
n\biggl\langle \frac{1}{n}t\biggm| v\biggr\rangle=\langle t\mid v\rangle
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Informative answer, thanks.  The point of my example is to explain that linearity over Q is a consequence of distributive assumption alone (no scalars); hence, I cannot ``simply use linearity...'' instead linearity is the desired consequence.

Comment: @Algeboy In that case, why not a proof by induction?

Comment: It is a proof by induction, I just included a simplified snippet where the latex went sideways on me and I wanted understand what was happening in case I encounter similar in the future.

Comment: @Algeboy I added how I'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

| can grow to the requested size, but <> has no arbitrary size extension so is limited to a fixed font-dependent set of sizes